# How do I pass values to a vertex shader's attribute array in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, glsl

In my vertex shader, I have

```
in float data[6];
```

That means that if I have 100 vertices, I want to pass 600 floats.  `glVertexAttribPointer` only supports sizes up to 4.  If I use size 1, then will it automatically pick up the 6 elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An attribute array in glsl is treated as a number of independent attributes with consecutive attribute locations. You'll have to setup the vertex attribute pointer for each them separately.

If you query the location of the first element with `idx = glGetAttribLocation(program_index, "data")`, then `data[1]` will have location `idx + 1`. You can then loop over them and call `glVertexAttribPointer*` with the index and the correct byte offset for each of the array elements.